# How to separate two static classes

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, design-patterns

my data access layer get connection data from DBConfig static class with static fields (ServerName,DBName,UserName,Password) .

now i need to establish two connections with different DBConfig ,, i tried to make another dll project then  add my dal to it to establish another connection from another assembly  ,, when i tried to add resulted dll as reference to the main project and try to change DBConfig data then it changes the main project's dbconfig class fields

Main project

```
static void Main()
{
     DBConfig.DbName = "InvDB";
     DBConfig.Password = "3343402";
     DBConfig.ServerName ="ziad-pc";
     DBConfig.UserName = "admin";
     DBConfig.Lang = "AR";
     GLINVSERVICES.ServiceConfig.Init("ZIAD-PC", "GLTest", "admin", "3343402");
}
```

Another DLL Project

```
namespace GLINVSERVICES
{
public static  class ServiceConfig
{
    public static void Init(string ServerName, string DBName, string UserName, string Password)
    {
        DBConfig.Datatype = EgxDataType.Mssql;
        DBConfig.DbName = DBName;
        DBConfig.Lang = "AR";
        DBConfig.ServerName = ServerName;
        DBConfig.UserName = UserName;
        DBConfig.Password = Password;
    }                     
}
}
```

i need to separate DBConfig static class so that i can establish different connections

Comment: I lost my Internet connection, I edited my answer just now.

Answer (score 5):

Move away from static classes. Your issue here clearly shows why they will get you into serious trouble.  Rather, you should refactor your code to use an *instance* of DBConfig, and inject that instance where it is needed.

Comment: but this static class based on it hundred lines of codes :(

Comment: @ZiadELNaggar hundreds? Count yourself lucky that it is not in the thousands :) face it, you're code is bad and I'm sorry that I cannot give you any "quicker" solution. But hey, better to fix it, no?

Answer (score 0):

**A**wful way to resolve your problem is instantiate your object in another domain (minimum changes).

1. Create a sub-class of `MarshalByRefObject` that refers to your static class.
2. Create new Domain
3. Use `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` method of `AppDomain` object to create an object in another domain with separate static domain.

For more information see [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**B**etter way is refactoring your code:

1. Change your static class to a singleton class.
2. Everywhere you see compiler error, change it to use your singleton instance.
3. Now, create another property to refer your second instance and use that in your purpose.

Your code will be something like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private readonly static YourClass _firstInstance = new YourClass();
    private readonly static YourClass _secondInstance = new YourClass();

    public YourClass Instance{
        get { return _firstInstance;}
    }

    public YourClass AnotherInstance{
        get { return _secondInstance;}
    }
}
```

**Note:** Every time you are creating a cohesive class and you think you just need one instance of that class, make your class singleton.

Comment: Check my solution and i need some clarifying about ur solution , thank's in advance :)

Comment: @ZiadELNaggar: When you want to have two separate instance of a static class, you can use first method without any change. But that isn't recommended.

Comment: could you give me an example ?

Comment: @ZiadELNaggar: In [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example if `Worker` be an static class, it could have different static variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting piece of codes between

```
        //permanently change DBConfig Fields 
        DBConfig.SetGLConnection("ziad-pc", "GLTest", "admin", "3343402"); 
        DBConfig.ChangeDatabase(EgxDataType.GLConnection,"GLTest");
         // here 
        DataAccess.CommitDatabaseChanging(); //Retrieve Last Connection Data
```

Comment: You needed two instance of a static class, right? Now, how this solution resolve your problem in general?

Comment: No i found this solution takes more time to resolve it , so i solve my main issue to make my Data Access Layer have a multi connections

Comment: Is `DBConfig` your connection? Now where is two instance of this static class?

Comment: yes DBConfig contains my connection data and can not contain more than one connection , i avoid code refactoring cause it'll take more time to handle .. so i create ChangeDatabase() method to temporary change DBConfig connection data while executing command in another database and finally retrieve my original connection data and assign it to DBConfig using CommitDatabaseChanging()

Comment: It's very situational dude :) If changing connection doesn't cost much, you can do this. If doesn't you can create another class that provide to object and according to the object you get it changes between this connections. However I'm glad your problem is resolved :)

Comment: Changing connection is temporary on the level of method ... thank's for your interest :)